# JavaScript equivalent of PHP's preg_replace

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I am using a simple regex to replace break tags with newlines:

```
br_regex = /<br>/;
input_content = input_content.replace(br_regex, "\n");
```

This only replaces the first instance of a break tag, but I need to replace all. `preg_match_all()` would do the trick in PHP, but I'd like to know the JavaScript equivalent.

Comment: As you don't need to match a regex pattern, you should be using str_replace() in PHP instead of preg_match_all() for your example:

$str = str_replace('<br>', "\n", $str);

Comment: You should really change title saying preg_replace and not preg_match_all, this is confusing and doesn't help when searching

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Use the global flag, `g`:

```
foo.replace(/<br>/g,"\n")
```

Answer (score 18):

JS idiom for non-Regexp global replace:

```
input_content.split('<br>').join('\n')
```

Comment: I feel dirty using this but it works and is the only way if the regex expression is base 64 decoded. TY :)

Comment: Hi @bobince, Asker wanted a RegEx based solution, why do you answer this?

Comment: @Tamim The regex solution had already been given; this is an alternative as for simple string replacement regex isn't necessary.