# preg_replace equivalent in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex, preg-replace

While searching for my answer I found this [Is there an equivalent in jQuery to PHP's `preg_replace()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673729/is-there-an-equivalent-in-jquery-to-phps-preg-replace)

But the thing is I want to actually match an pattern and then take the content in it and put it in a other var.

Ok..  i think I'm confusing people more than anything..

this is the code that would work in php.

```
$intBetweenTheTwoCurlyBraket = preg_replace("/^{([0-9]+)}.*/",'$1',"{132} TestString");
```

Right now what i have is.

```
 intBetweenTheTwoCurlyBraket = item.value.replace(/^{([0-9]+)}.*/i,"$1");
```

But it doesnt work.
What im I doing Wrong.

Thanks for any help!

---

For some reason escaping the curly bracket did the job,..

Thanks for all your inputs My question is now resolved

Comment: Please refer this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/407264/674127

Comment: "{132} TestString" should turn into "123 TestString"?

Comment: What is the expected output? `"{132} TestString".replace(/^{([0-9]+)}.*/i,"$1")` would be `"132"`

Comment: your js regex is already identical to the php version (except the `i` modifier, which isn't necessary). If it's not working, your issue is somewhere else, like not pulling the right value to replace (`item.value`)

Comment: For some reason escaping the curly bracket did the job,..  Thanks for all your inputs My question is resolved now.

Comment: @NicolasRacine: bracket have special meaning in regexes, You must escape them.

Answer (score 1):

Escape `{ and }` so use this regex in JS:

```
/^\{([0-9]+)\}.*/
```